# How to find out the source package / traceback of an error message in KDE?

Tags: debian, kde, error-handling, plasma

When I start plasmashell with `kstart5 plasmashell` in Debian11/KDE I get an error message (`error creating screencast "Failed to connect PipeWire context"`) that I'd like to see the source package that is throwing this error or a full traceback if possible.

How can this be done?

---

The error must be thrown somewhere, probably not plasmashell itself but some package that it launches. I'd like to see at least which package.

Another thing that would be interesting to check is how kdeconnect gets started despite it being configured not to autostart (currently it shows `Permission denied` errors because I changed the permissions of the executable to prevent it from getting started).

Answer (score 1):

A Debian source search for [“Failed to connect PipeWire context”](https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=Failed%20to%20connect%20PipeWire%20context) reveals a number of possibilities; given the context, the error is coming from [`kwin`’s “screencast” plugin](https://sources.debian.org/src/kwin/4:5.26.0-1/src/plugins/screencast/pipewirecore.cpp/?hl=84#L84). Searching for [“error creating screencast”](https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=error%20creating%20screencast) shows that the error is shown by [`plasma-workspace`’s `libtaskmanager`](https://sources.debian.org/src/plasma-workspace/4:5.26.0-2/libtaskmanager/declarative/screencastingrequest.cpp/?hl=80#L80).

To get a full traceback you’d need to run the relevant program under a debugger.

Comment: Do you know how to do so? I tried running plasmashell with gdb as described [here](https://community.kde.org/Plasma/Debugging#Attach_gdb_to_the_plasmashell_process) (or [here](https://community.kde.org/Guidelines_and_HOWTOs/Debugging)) but it returns `Attaching to process 1234 ptrace: Operation not permitted.`. In the KDE System Monitor (process manager) it displays nothing in the tree under kwin_wayland or under plasmashell. Let me know if there's sth else I should/could check (I'm not using screencasting & only recorded screen with screenrecorder once). Maybe caused by firejailed firefox-esr

Comment: Are you running Firefox when you get the message? Your question ties the behaviour to plasmashell, but if you’re also starting Firefox it could come from there.

Comment: Running it yes, but not launching it. I'll try if it occurs without Firefox running and it doesn't occur on another machine with nearly same setup even when I use firefox-esr on it. I would probably need to debug plasmashell.